# queryUsageStats interval duration

Tags: android, usagestatsmanager

I'm using UsageStatsManager API to get usage statistics for a certain time interval. All works fine if I use the predefined intervals i.e. INTERVAL_DAILY, INTERVAL_WEEKLY, INTERVAL_MONTHLY, INTERVAL_YEARLY. But if I want to view the data for the past 2 or 3 hours, I am getting today's data for the whole day. I have tried using Calendars and System.currentTimeMillis() but that didn't give me filtered results.

Calendar approach :

```
Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
startCalendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -2);

Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

And pass this to queryUsageStats method like this:

```
usageList = usm.queryUsageStats(interval, startCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), endCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

where interval is INTERVAL_BEST.

System.currentTimeMillis() approach :

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - 7200*1000 // 7200 seconds i.e. 2 hrs

long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Pass this to queryUsageStats just like above :

```
usageList = usm.queryUsageStats(interval, startTime, endTime);
```

where interval is again INTERVAL_BEST.

I'd like to know whether it's possible to get data for this duration i.e. less than a day, as the INTERVAL_BEST hasn't been documented properly to include this information. Any help would be appreciated as I'm stuck on this problem.

Comment: Would be helpful if the down-voter could comment the reason or maybe answer this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html) doc says:

> A request for data in the middle of a time interval will include that interval.

It seems that usage data is stored in buckets, and minimum bucket is a day, so you can't query usage stats for period less than a day. Even if you query a one-hour interval for a particular day, usage stats for the whole day is returned.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party, but I think this might be useful to some.

You could use the `queryEvents(long startTime, long endTime)` from UsageStatsManager for achieving the desired result. The method could look like this (inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238481/android-usagestatsmanager-not-returning-correct-daily-results?noredirect=1&lq=1)):

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public HashMap<String, AppUsageInfo> queryUsageStatistics(Context context, long startTime, long endTime) {
    UsageEvents.Event currentEvent;
    List<UsageEvents.Event> allEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, AppUsageInfo> map = new HashMap<>();
    UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
    assert mUsageStatsManager != null;
    // Here we query the events from startTime till endTime.
    UsageEvents usageEvents = mUsageStatsManager.queryEvents(startTime, endTime);

    // go over all events.
    while (usageEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
        currentEvent = new UsageEvents.Event();
        usageEvents.getNextEvent(currentEvent);
        String packageName = currentEvent.getPackageName();
        if (currentEvent.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_RESUMED || currentEvent.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_PAUSED ||
                    currentEvent.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_STOPPED) {
            allEvents.add(currentEvent); // an extra event is found, add to all events list.
            // taking it into a collection to access by package name
            if (!map.containsKey(packageName)) {
                map.put(packageName, new AppUsageInfo());
            }
        }
    }

    // iterate through all events.
    for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.size() - 1; i++) {
        UsageEvents.Event event0 = allEvents.get(i);
        UsageEvents.Event event1 = allEvents.get(i + 1);

        //for launchCount of apps in time range
        if (!event0.getPackageName().equals(event1.getPackageName()) && event1.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_RESUMED) {
            // if true, E1 (launch event of an app) app launched
            Objects.requireNonNull(map.get(event1.getPackageName())).launchCount++;
        }

        //for UsageTime of apps in time range
        if (event0.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_RESUMED &&
                (event1.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_PAUSED || event1.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_STOPPED)
                && event0.getPackageName().equals(event1.getPackageName())) {
            long diff = event1.getTimeStamp() - event0.getTimeStamp();
            Objects.requireNonNull(map.get(event0.getPackageName())).timeInForeground += diff;
        }
    }
    // and return the map.
    return map;
}
```

The AppUsageInfo class would be:

```
public class AppUsageInfo {

    public long timeInForeground;
    public int launchCount;

    AppUsageInfo() {
        this.timeInForeground = 0;
        this.launchCount = 0;
    }
}
```

To then get the usage stats for the last two hours, simply call

```
Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
startCalendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -2);
Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

HashMap<String, AppUsageInfo> result = queryUsageStatistics(context, startCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), endCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
```