# Getting wrong data from stats usage Android

Tags: android, android-calendar, usage-statistics, android-date

i am tying to retrieve User usage data using the Usagestats ...but i'm getting wrong data...i want to get daily usage "From 00:00:00  to 23:59:59 "

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

      cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -1); \\ the missing line


    UsageStatsManager uStateManager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
   List<UsageStats> usageList = uStateManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, cal.getTimeInMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis());
```

when  i use .getTotalTimeInForeground() i get a different result than expected ? Can you help me in setting the right way cause i tried alot and different ways without getting the expected result?
Thanks

Comment: Not an expert with the `UsageStatsManager`, but are you sure passing the calendar time as 2nd parameter is correct? 2nd parameter awaits a starting time, and just passing there `Calendar.getInstance()` is almost equal to `System.currentTimeMillis()`, so you're querying usage stats for like 10ms timeframe. Maybe try passing there `0`.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,actually i missed writing here one line of  the code ..which is 

cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -1);  ...i edited the code above...so please recheck it

Answer (score 3):

This question is a bit old  but I've been battling with the `UsageStatsManager` for a fair bit of time now and have found out a few things which might be useful to others. Here's a few tips to help you with this problem.

- `Calendar.getInstance()` returns "a `Calendar` object whose calendar fields have been initialized with the current date and **time**." ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)) So if you're looking to get the daily usage at those times, you need to set them manually to midnight.
- It looks like the `UsageStatsManager` uses UTC time to store all of their data. So when querying, make sure to adjust the time for that.
- I have found the daily usage stats using `queryUsageStats` to be completely unreliable. Even with UTC time adjustment, it seems that depending on the time of day it'll send back yesterday's stats instead of today's stats.

There's not much documentation as to how they decide which stats to take into account when you query this method, which makes it fairly unreliable. If calculating daily stats, I would highly recommend using the `UsageEvent`s instead and manually calculating the time. The calculated time matches what is returned by `queryUsageStats` (provided that that method returns the right stats), which for me is proof enough that it's reliable enough for foreground tracking. There's more about how to do that [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238481/android-usagestatsmanager-not-returning-correct-daily-results), and I have added my implementation of it there ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50647945/3444398)).