# Android: get UsageStats per hour

Tags: java, android, usage-statistics

I use `UsageStats` feature of Android, but the smallest interval is `DAILY INTERVAL`.

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
List<UsageStats> appList = manager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - DAY_IN_MILLI_SECONDS, time);
```

How can I get `UsageStats` in an hourly interval?

Comment: so you need to run your code every hour..

Comment: I read that even if the time frame you picked lasts five minutes, if you picked INTERVAL_WEEKLY as intervalType you will get all the stats inside that interval.

Comment: @Rougher Is your problem solved? Will it be helpful for you, if I provide the correct answer now? I have worked a lot on this area.

Comment: Hey @SabbirAhmed. I still search a solution. Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Rougher Okay, I will try my best to help you.

Comment: Please, check the answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238481/android-usagestatsmanager-not-returning-correct-daily-results#45380396). I have learned from that one.

**How can we collect app usage data for customized time range (e.g. for per 1 hour)?**

We have to call [`queryEvents(long begin_time, long  end_time)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html#queryEvents(long,%20long)) method as it will provide us all data starting from `begin_time` to `end_time`. It give us each app data through `foreground` and `background` events instead of total spent time like [`queryUsageStats()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html#queryUsageStats(int,%20long,%20long)) method. So, using foreground and background events time stamp, we can count the number of times an app has been launched and also can find out the usage duration for each app.

**Implementation to Collect Last 1 Hour App Usage Data**

At first, add the following line in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and also request user to get permission of usage access.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" />
```

Add the following lines inside any method

```
    long hour_in_mil = 1000*60*60; // In Milliseconds
    long end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long start_time = end_time - hour_in_mil;
```

Then, call the method `getUsageStatistics()`

```
    getUsageStatistics(start_time, end_time);
```

*getUsageStatistics methiod*

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
void getUsageStatistics(long start_time, long end_time) {

    UsageEvents.Event currentEvent;
  //  List<UsageEvents.Event> allEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, AppUsageInfo> map = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, List<UsageEvents.Event>> sameEvents = new HashMap<>();

    UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);

    if (mUsageStatsManager != null) {
        // Get all apps data from starting time to end time
        UsageEvents usageEvents = mUsageStatsManager.queryEvents(start_time, end_time);

        // Put these data into the map
        while (usageEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
            currentEvent = new UsageEvents.Event();
            usageEvents.getNextEvent(currentEvent);
            if (currentEvent.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_RESUMED ||
                    currentEvent.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_PAUSED) {
              //  allEvents.add(currentEvent);
                String key = currentEvent.getPackageName();
                if (map.get(key) == null) {
                    map.put(key, new AppUsageInfo(key));
                    sameEvents.put(key,new ArrayList<UsageEvents.Event>());
                }
                sameEvents.get(key).add(currentEvent);
            }
        }

        // Traverse through each app data which is grouped together and count launch, calculate duration
        for (Map.Entry<String,List<UsageEvents.Event>> entry : sameEvents.entrySet()) {
            int totalEvents = entry.getValue().size();
            if (totalEvents > 1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < totalEvents - 1; i++) {
                    UsageEvents.Event E0 = entry.getValue().get(i);
                    UsageEvents.Event E1 = entry.getValue().get(i + 1);

                    if (E1.getEventType() == 1 || E0.getEventType() == 1) {
                        map.get(E1.getPackageName()).launchCount++;
                    }

                    if (E0.getEventType() == 1 && E1.getEventType() == 2) {
                        long diff = E1.getTimeStamp() - E0.getTimeStamp();
                        map.get(E0.getPackageName()).timeInForeground += diff;
                    }
                }
            }

    // If First eventtype is ACTIVITY_PAUSED then added the difference of start_time and Event occuring time because the application is already running.
            if (entry.getValue().get(0).getEventType() == 2) {
                long diff = entry.getValue().get(0).getTimeStamp() - start_time;
                map.get(entry.getValue().get(0).getPackageName()).timeInForeground += diff;
            }
            
    // If Last eventtype is ACTIVITY_RESUMED then added the difference of end_time and Event occuring time because the application is still running .
            if (entry.getValue().get(totalEvents - 1).getEventType() == 1) {
                long diff = end_time - entry.getValue().get(totalEvents - 1).getTimeStamp();
                map.get(entry.getValue().get(totalEvents - 1).getPackageName()).timeInForeground += diff;
            }
        }
    
    smallInfoList = new ArrayList<>(map.values());

    // Concatenating data to show in a text view. You may do according to your requirement
    for (AppUsageInfo appUsageInfo : smallInfoList)
    {
        // Do according to your requirement
        strMsg = strMsg.concat(appUsageInfo.packageName + " : " + appUsageInfo.launchCount + "\n\n");
    }

    TextView tvMsg = findViewById(R.id.MA_TvMsg);
    tvMsg.setText(strMsg);
       
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

*AppUsageInfo.class*

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

class AppUsageInfo {
    Drawable appIcon; // You may add get this usage data also, if you wish.
    String appName, packageName;
    long timeInForeground;
    int launchCount;

    AppUsageInfo(String pName) {
        this.packageName=pName;
    }
}
```

**How can I customize these codes to collect per 1 hour data?**

As you want to get per hour data, please change the `end_time` and `start_time` value for every hour data. For instance: If I would try to collect past per hour data *(for past 2 hour data).* I would do the following thing.

```
    long end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long start_time = end_time - (1000*60*60);

    getUsageStatistics(start_time, end_time);

    end_time =  start_time;
    start_time = start_time - hour_in_mil;

    getUsageStatistics(start_time, end_time);
```

However, you may use a `Handler` to skip repeatedly writing `start_time` and `end_time` to change value of these variables. Each time data will be collected for one hour, a task will be completed and after automatically changing the values of the variables, you will again call the `getUsageStatistics` method.

**Note:** Maybe, you will not be able to retrieve data for more than past 7.5 days as [events are only kept by the system for a few days](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html#queryEvents(long,%20long)).

Comment: @SabbirAhmedת The Great Solution! I only changed UsageEvents.Event.MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND to UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_RESUMED, UsageEvents.Event.MOVE_TO_BACKGROUND to UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_PAUSED due to deprecation in API 29

Comment: @Rougher Very happy to help you. Also thanks for this information (deprecation in API 29).

Comment: Hi @Rougher we have a project that needs this logic and if you are interested in helping out, please contact me.  jonathan dot bell at rysis dot co dot za.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Calendar cal = (Calendar) Calendar.getInstance().clone();
    //I used this and it worked, only for 7 days and a half ago 
    if (daysAgo == 0) {
        //Today - I only count from 00h00m00s today to present

        end = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        start = LocalDate.now().toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toInstant().getMillis();
    } else {
        long todayStartOfDayTimeStamp = LocalDate.now().toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toInstant().getMillis();
        if (mDaysAgo == -6) {
            //6 days ago, only get events in time -7 days to -7.5 days

            cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, daysAgo + 1);
            end = cal .getTimeInMillis();
            start = end - 43200000;
        } else {
            //get events from 00h00m00s to  23h59m59s
            //Current calendar point to 0h0m today
            cal.setTimeInMillis(todayStartOfDayTimeStamp);
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, daysAgo + 1);
            end = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
            start = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it's possible, even if you ask for data in the middle of an interval, it looks like the data is stored in buckets and the minimum bucket is a day.
In [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html) documentation, it says:

> A request for data in the middle of a time interval will include that interval.

Also, `INTERVAL_BEST` is not a real interval, it just selects one of the available intervals for the given time range. In 
[UsageStatsManager.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.java) source code, it says:

```
/**
 * The number of available intervals. Does not include {@link #INTERVAL_BEST}, since it
 * is a pseudo interval (it actually selects a real interval).
 * {@hide}
 */
public static final int INTERVAL_COUNT = 4;
```

Comment: I wrote it in the comments for my post.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, Android is providing minimum `INTERVAL_DAILY`. But for the best result, you can use `INTERVAL_BEST`. Android is giving the best interval timer for the given time range in `queryUsageStats(int, long, long)`.

Happy coding...

Comment: I saw INTERVAL_BEST, but I don't understand how can I know what is the interval? I want on each hour to get something like: whatsapp - 30 minutes, youtube - 25 minutes, facebook - 5 minutes.