# Android time usage of other application in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, usagestatsmanager

I want to know how much time i spent in my application (facebook , messenger ... ) in android studio

I've seen this post [How to Get the Time spent on an application in Android Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32825854/how-to-get-the-time-spent-on-an-application-in-android-programmatically)

But i have an empty list from `usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats`

Any other valuable source or an idea how to correct the issue that i am facing.

Comment: Hi Yagami Light, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59113756/android-get-usagestats-per-hour/59362638#59362638) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager) require `PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS`, which sounds like a [system level](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS) permission.

> Protection level: signature|privileged|development|appop|retailDemo
>
> A convenience method that queries for all stats in the given range
> (using the best interval for that range), merges the resulting data,
> and keys it by package name. See queryUsageStats(int, long, long).
>
> The caller must have Manifest.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS

Comment: Can you please provide more details about a potentiel solution ( add a method asking for permission ...

Comment: @YagamiLight unless your app got a system permission, meaning it is signed by same signature as the OS apps, then you can't get it. There is no way for asking it in run time.

Comment: do you mean it's impossible to create an app that display android usage of other apps ?

Comment: Yes, unless this is a built in system app