# How do I use Android UsageStatsManager to fetch the currently running application names?

Tags: java, android, usagestatsmanager

I am trying to fetch all the application names that are currently running in my android phone, and display them in the logcat. This is done in the background, so I am using the `service` class. My code is as following:

```
public class Timer extends Service {
  
    public Timer() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if(!needPermissionForBlocking(getApplicationContext())) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS));
        }
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager)this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,  time - 10000*10000, time);
        if (appList.size() == 0) {
            Log.d("Executed app", "######### NO APP FOUND ##########" );
        }
        else {
            SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
            for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
                Log.d("Executed app", "usage stats executed : " +usageStats.getPackageName() + "\t\t ID: ");
                mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
                if (!mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                    String currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
                    Log.d("app",currentApp);
                }
            }

        }
        
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    public static boolean needPermissionForBlocking(Context context){
        try {
            PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
            ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            AppOpsManager appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
            int mode = appOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, applicationInfo.uid, applicationInfo.packageName);
            return  (mode != AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

But no matter how many apps I run, the code shows the log everytime

> "Executed app", "######### NO APP FOUND ##########"

I have also added the following permission in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why can't it fetch the running apps on my device?

Comment: "Why can't it fetch the running apps on my device?" -- among perhaps other things, that is not what `UsageStatsManager` is for. `UsageStatsManager` is for historical usage data, not the current state, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: So, there's no way of fetching the list of currently running apps ?

Comment: @Abhishek, can you please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59113756/android-get-usagestats-per-hour/59362638#59362638). I guess this is the answer what you are looking for.