# Android Usage Stats Manager, how can I find out the apps for a specific time perios (couple of minutes)?

Tags: android, google-people-api, usage-statistics, usagestatsmanager

I'm only a hobby programmer, but I have this question I need answered for work. I would love to get some concrete answers, thank you so much!

As I understand it, we can't specifially ask the Usage Stats Manager for the Most Used Apps for a short interval (e. g. 10 minutes).

The smallest interval is one day right?
When does this day start?
Is it the last 24 hours and I could find out the Apps through generating a list right at the start of my interval and one right at the end and calculate the set of apps used during my interval afterwards?
Or does a day always start at midnight, if I asked for the stats at 11 am, would it only give me the apps from midnight to 11 am or the day before 11 am to today 11am?

Thank you so much!!

I've searched through the Android documentation, multiple websites but I can't find the answer to this question.

Comment: Hi, you may look into this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59113756/android-get-usagestats-per-hour/59362638#59362638