# UsageStatsManager not returning correct weekly or monthly results

Tags: android, usage-statistics, usagestatsmanager

### Question

I want to retrieve a list of `UsageStats` per week or month. However, the output often has overlapping intervals, e.g. Wed Apr 29 until Mon May 04, when I'm requesting monthly data (see the latest result of the time stamps below).

**So my question is:** how can I cleanly get the usage stats for a particular week (e.g. Mon - Sun) or month (e.g. Apr 1 - Apr 31) using the UsageStatsManager?

### Background

In my Android application, I'm using the `UsageStatsManager` to retrieve the total time in foreground per week/month. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431795/how-to-use-usagestatsmanager) about how to use the `UsageStatsManager` has been very helpful already, as well as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238481/android-usagestatsmanager-not-returning-correct-daily-results?noredirect=1&lq=1) about the `UsageStatsManager` producing the wrong daily results (I'm using that method for the daily usage stats, which is working fine now).

### Problem

The trouble starts when I try to retrieve the usage stats for weekly/monthly interval. The [UsageStatsManager documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager#top_of_page) states that

> Usage data is aggregated into time intervals: days, weeks, months, and years.

**But the output I get from querying the UsageStatsManager is very different**. An example of how I'm retrieving the list of UsageStats objects for the last two months:

```java
    Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    long endTime = endCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
    Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    startCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -2); // since two months.
    long startTime = startCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
    UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
    List<UsageStats> result = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_MONTHLY, startTime, endTime);
```

However, when I go over the `List<UsageStats> result` and log the time stamps of the packages and their foreground time, I get a bunch of time stamps, but they are not in a monthly interval at all. An example of time stamps I retrieved for the Contacts app from the `result`:

```
ForegroundTime: 4447 first=Wed Mar 04 03:53:28 GMT+01:00 2020 last=Fri Mar 06 11:46:18 GMT+01:00 2020
ForegroundTime: 176383 first=Fri Mar 06 11:46:18 GMT+01:00 2020 last=Tue Mar 17 07:53:54 GMT+01:00 2020
ForegroundTime: 14337 first=Tue Mar 17 07:53:54 GMT+01:00 2020 last=Tue Mar 17 20:03:31 GMT+01:00 2020
ForegroundTime: 0 first=Tue Mar 17 20:03:31 GMT+01:00 2020 last=Fri Mar 20 14:32:26 GMT+01:00 2020
ForegroundTime: 0 first=Fri Mar 20 14:32:26 GMT+01:00 2020 last=Mon Mar 23 00:12:11 GMT+01:00 2020
ForegroundTime: 0 first=Mon Mar 23 04:27:16 GMT+01:00 2020 last=Mon Mar 23 17:00:29 GMT+01:00 2020
ForegroundTime: 0 first=Mon Mar 23 17:00:29 GMT+01:00 2020 last=Sat Mar 28 00:52:10 GMT+01:00 2020
ForegroundTime: 0 first=Sat Mar 28 00:52:10 GMT+01:00 2020 last=Fri Apr 03 06:45:08 GMT+02:00 2020
ForegroundTime: 81481 first=Fri Apr 03 06:45:08 GMT+02:00 2020 last=Thu Apr 09 18:04:05 GMT+02:00 2020
ForegroundTime: 0 first=Thu Apr 09 18:04:05 GMT+02:00 2020 last=Thu Apr 16 10:31:23 GMT+02:00 2020
ForegroundTime: 157189 first=Thu Apr 16 10:31:23 GMT+02:00 2020 last=Sun Apr 26 02:10:31 GMT+02:00 2020
ForegroundTime: 0 first=Sun Apr 26 02:10:31 GMT+02:00 2020 last=Wed Apr 29 13:21:12 GMT+02:00 2020
ForegroundTime: 43516 first=Wed Apr 29 13:21:12 GMT+02:00 2020 last=Mon May 04 17:45:43 GMT+02:00 2020
```

which seems to be partitioned almost randomly into intervals.

Any links/explanation as to why UsageStatsManager has this behaviour, or an example of an open-source application that is using the UsageStatsManager for querying weeks/months/years would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using queryEvents function for daily stats?

Comment: Yes I am, but that part (as mentioned) is fine. The trouble I'm having is for querying the weeks and months.

Answer (score 1):

I might not be able to solve the issue but I will suggest a way around it which is using *queryEvents* function for all of them - daily, weekly and monthly data.

Querying weekly data(data of last 7 days) by this function is similar to querying daily data by it. (you mentioned that you have already implemented the function for daily data)

As for monthly data, you cannot directly use the function since events are kept by system for around one week as said in documentation. You need to store usage data in a local database and query from it.

Comment: Indeed, but this workaround would not be ideal, since I would be implementing the functionality of the UsageStatsManager class myself, plus users would have to wait for their weekly and monthly data until it is available, from the time they start using the application.

Comment: Well, users don’t have to wait for weekly data. But yeah, for monthly data, they do and this is the only loophole of this workaround sadly.

Comment: Thanks. I will wait with accepting your answer, since it doesn't solve the original question, but it is helpful. One question, you mentioned that querying weekly data is possible, but for some reason I can't get it to work for usage times longer than a week in the past. Could you elaborate on how you would achieve this?

Comment: Well, I shouldn’t have used the term "weekly". By " weekly data" I actually wanted to mean data of last 7 days. I've edited my answer accordingly