# How to use UsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(...)?

Tags: android, usagestatsmanager

### Background

I want usage data about different apps on my company's tablets. The optimal solution spans the greatest amount of time. I read [here](https://medium.com/@quiro91/show-app-usage-with-usagestatsmanager-d47294537dab) that I should be able to get data for up to two years past with some of the UsageStatsManager queries.

### What I've tried

I figured that *UsageStatsManager.queryAndAggregateUsageStats(..)* would do the trick but I found it would only return intervals of up to around one week.
Since the "aggregate" query wasn't working I tried this code so I could explicitly declare bucket size:

```
val appStats = statsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_YEARLY, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE)
```

I tried using multiple different time intervals including:

```
val appStats = statsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_YEARLY,curTime - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(730), curTime)
```

The longest interval I am able to get is around one week.

Example log:

> ```
> Name: com.example.myusagestatsmanagertestapp
> -->  Beginning: Tue Jul 20 10:16:41 CDT 2021
> -->     Ending: Mon Jul 26 21:20:47 CDT 2021
> --> Time in FG: 186
> ```

### Where I am now

I must be doing something wrong as the **INTERVAL_YEARLY** constant isn't deprecated. However, I have deduced from other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61596881/usagestatsmanager-not-returning-correct-weekly-or-monthly-results) one or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238481/android-usagestatsmanager-not-returning-correct-daily-results) one that this API has been sketchy.

My next move is to build my own stats via *UsageStatsManager.queryEvents(..)* which seems more consistent and clear cut.

### Questions

1. What is the problem?
2. Are the UsageStatsManager data even worth trusting?

### Specs and Code

My device is Android 9.0 Samsung Galaxy Active Tab2.

Here is the full function!

```
    private fun getIndividualAppUsageDuration(
    statsManager: UsageStatsManager,
    curTime: Long
): Map<String, Long> {
    val appMap: MutableMap<String, Long> = mutableMapOf()

    val apps = statsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_MONTHLY,curTime - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(60), curTime)

    for(app in apps) {
        appMap[app.packageName] = app.totalTimeInForeground
        Log.d("TAG_1", "...\n" +
                "Name: ${app.packageName}\n" +
                "-->  Beginning: ${stringifyMilli(app.firstTimeStamp)}\n" +
                "-->     Ending: ${stringifyMilli(app.lastTimeStamp)}\n" +
                "--> Time in FG: ${TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(app.totalTimeInForeground)}" )
    }

    return appMap
}
```

The permissions I use!

> ```
>     <uses-permission
>         android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
>         tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
> ```